# PostgreSQL table id won't auto-increment

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a table in my database that is in dire need of an auto-incrementing field. To create one, I ran these following SQL statements towards the aforementioned database:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE table_id_seq
    INCREMENT 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    START 1
    CACHE 1;

ALTER TABLE ONLY table ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('table_id_seq'::regclass);
ALTER TABLE ONLY table
    ADD CONSTRAINT table_id PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

However, when I try to INSERT any two values into table I still get a primary key violation error. I don't understand what I'm missing to make it auto-incrementing.

Comment: Show us your insert statements.

Comment: I'm using entity framework and I'm not sure how I can see the autogenerated insert statements.

Comment: Without seeing the actual inserts it's impossible to answer your question.

Comment: The insert is probably inserting a value into the id column

Comment: Some ORMs ignore the auto-incrementing values. Doctrine in particular, fetches 10 ids in advance to "speed up" inserts.

Comment: Entity framework has no problems with inserting auto-incrementing values with the other tables, so I don't believe that to be the case. (I accidently deleted this one and I'm trying to restore it).
@Denis that might very well be the case, but I don't think its EF's fault (since it works on other tables)

a_horse_with_no_name: I'm sorry but the pgadmin.log only shows sql which is undecipherable.

Comment: What's the exact error message?  (PostgreSQL's error messages are usually very good.)  If there's already data in the table, starting the new sequence with the value 1 probably won't work. Start with a more appropriate number.

Comment: The exacts error message I get in visual studio is {"duplicate key value violates unique constraint \"table_id\""}.

So I tried using a normal insert statement in pgadmin, and it works perfectly, so the issue might be with EF. I have updated the EF model from the database and before it would work right out of the box, but now if doesn't.

Comment: check the current value of `table_id_seq` befere and after the insert command and see if is incremented. If current value is not incremented maybe postgresql does not invoke the sequence for default value, so probably, your insert command try to enter a value in the id field.

Comment: OK, so I found the solution. In my infinite retardation I, at first didn't update the EF model after changing the database. Afterwards I didn't save the model after updating it. Now I did both and it works.
I sincerely doubt this question will be helpful for anyone else, do I delete it or parade my stupidity for all eternity?

Thanks all for the help, I do appreciate it.

Comment: @user1815201 just post a quick summary as an answer. It'll remind someone else to do that if they have the same thing later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Entity Framework and you make changes to a database, you must remember to update the model from database. Also, you have to save the model before you test your code again or else it will use the old model, and not get your the results you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

After the sequence’s already created, we can call NEXTVAL('table_id_seq') to generate a new value automatically.

**1. Link the sequence to the unique column**

```
ALTER TABLE ONLY 
ALTER COLUMN id 
SET DEFAULT NEXTVAL('table_id_seq');
ALTER TABLE ONLY table
    ADD CONSTRAINT table_id PRIMARY KEY (id);
```